# Publish and subscribe for a collection depending on a document field with different IDs with Meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am building a magnetic poetry game in Meteor

http://test-magnets.meteor.com/

The homepage allows everyone online to play on the same "fridge"  I want to have an option that allows you to create your own fridge without the public disturbing it.

I used Iron Router to generate a url based on the userID.  The magnets have a fridgeId.  The fridgeId for the home page is 1 and when a user goes into the url based on their userId, the magnets fridgeId gets updated to be the same as the userId.

Currently when you move a magnet in the homepage it also makes the change in the user's private fridge.  Is it possible to use publish and subscribe or the iron router just to update the database for the magnets depending on my generated fridgeId?  Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.  Thanks

-John

Here is some code I have now.

iron router

```
Router.map(function() {
this.route('home', {
    path: '/'
});
var user = Meteor.userId();
this.route('private', {
    path: '/' + user 
 });
});
```

magnets collection

```
  if (Meteor.isServer) {

   Meteor.publish('magnets', function(){
   return Magnets.find();
 });
}


if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Meteor.subscribe('magnets', function(){
  return Magnets.find();
 });
}
```

some helpers that set the fridgeId

```
Template.home.events = {
'click #new-board': function() {
    var user = Meteor.userId();
    var magnet = Magnets.findOne();
    Magnets.update({_id: magnet._id}, {$set: {fridgeId: user}});
 }
};

Template.private.events = {
'click #group-fridge': function() {
    var magnet = Magnets.findOne();
    Magnets.update({_id: magnet._id}, {$set: {fridgeId: 1}});
 }
};
```